# String <-> Number conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, types

All,

Below is the code that I have written in JS.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Fibonacci trial</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            var strRepresen = new String();
            var numberReprsen = new Number();
            strRepresen = "XXX";
            numberReprsen = 10;
            strRepresen = 5;
            numberReprsen = "XXX again";
            document.write(strRepresen);
            document.write(numberReprsen);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have following queries:

1 > I am not able to understand how the line `numberReprsen = "XXX again";` does not give an error or NaN when I have defined `numberReprsen` as a Number object.
2 > I have seen many scripts not writing `<script type = "text/javascript">`. Is it a standard or mandate to mention the script type?

Note: I am a **beginner** in Javascript.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp is a good resource for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not able to understand how the line `numberReprsen = "XXX again";` does not give an error or NaN when I have defined numberReprsen as a Number object.

Variables in JavaScript are not typed.  You have not defined numberReprsen as a Number variable.  You have defined it as a variable.  That it at one time happened to contain a Number object is irrelevant.  You can store *anything* in it.

> I have seen many scripts not writing `<script type = "text/javascript">`. Is it a standard or mandate to mention the script type?

I believe `type` is an attribute required by the more recent (X)HTML specifications.  But yes, generally, it is a good idea to specify.  I always do.

Comment: Thank you. So is it possible to check the type of a variable at any point ? something like isInteger() ?

Comment: Yes, but only in the most basic sense.  For example, if you do `var a = 1;` then `alert(typeof a);` will display "number".  But if you did `var a = new Number(1);` then `alert(typeof a);` will display "object" because the Number class essentially boxes a number in an object.

Comment: Oh, as a side note, there are specific techniques you can use to determine the type of an object, or if it is convertible to a type.  For example, `!isNaN(a)` will determine if `a` is a number, a `Number` object, or a string that can be successfully converted to a number.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your first question is concerned, Javascript is not a statically-typed language; it is a dynamically-typed language. Hence, types are associated with **values** and not with **variables**.

Initially `numberReprsen` is bound to a number, and later you are rebinding it to a string. Here, you're seeing exactly what I described; Javascript is typing the variable based on the **value** (which was initially a number, and then a string).

JavaScript has various ways to test the type of an object, one of which is duck typing.

To answer your second question, I think it is mandated by [X]HTML specs. Either way, I always specify a `type` attribute and I believe it is best practice.

Comment: yes. But the link[http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_Number.asp] shows that passing a String value to Number object gives a NaN

Comment: But you did not say `Number("XXX ...")`.  You said `"XXX ..."`.

Comment: You said `"XXX ...."` and not `Number("XXX ...")`. The latter will give you an error because the "constructor" expects a number.

Answer (score 1):

It won't raise an error because when you do:

```
numberReprsen = "XXX again";
```

You are actually changing its type to string and overwriting its previous value.

Comment: Technically, you are not changing the type of anything.  You are discarding one value and replacing it with another.  The variable has no type to begin with.